# How to copy a file/directory without changing its attributes

Tags: linux, file, ubuntu, copy

I want to copy a folder and files in it to another place preserving there attributes like create date, update date ,permissions etc..

How can i do that ?

Comment: Looks like this is not really  question, is it? Sorry, but this is not an "answer site"... Knowing what a command does is not topic here, that is much easier learned from the manual pages that come with the commands. As to the task mentioned in the title: it is _much_ easier to use the corresponding flags in the `cp` command offers which also allow to preserve things like file ownership and permissions.

Comment: @arkascha : Sorry, I actually posted the answer in question itself and forget to remove it.
But flags in cp command do not persists all your flags. May there are few which I don't know, if you can add that here,it will great.

Comment: I found my answer as quick, nice and easy way to get it done. So just thought to share. :)

Comment: Would you care to elaborate what "flags" do not persist with a cp -pPr command in your experience?

Comment: Thanks for sharing, I was not aware..!!! But my question was not invalid

Answer (score 0):

Just make a tar of that folder or file and extract it where ever you want.
Its attributes will be intact.

To create a tar.gz archive from a given folder you can use the following command

**tar -zcvf tar-archive-name.tar.gz source-folder-name**

This will compress the contents of source-folder-name to a tar.gz archive named tar-archive-name.tar.gz

To extract a tar.gz compressed archive you can use the following command

**tar -zxvf tar-archive-name.tar.gz**

And you are done :)